# Evolution vertical view

Tags: gnome, evolution

[image][help.gnome.org](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/mail-vertical-view.html.en) says that when you put Evolution in vertical view, the message list stacks the headers to make them more legible, like in Outlook. However, When I use vertical view, this doesn't happen and the message list is unreadable. Was this removed?

Comment: Can you post an example? I tested Vertical View and I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: I'm using 3.34; have never seen a view like the one described in your link. Going further through those docs, the view it shows for the main Email view page is really old - no **To Do** list, which has been there since at least v3.28.

Comment: OK, so it looks like the version in the repo is too old. I can't find any alternate repo, and trying to install the deb results in missing dependancies. Is there a way to get the newest Evolution in Bionic?

Comment: I'm using the flatpak version, currently on 3.34.2.

Comment: I just installed 3.36 on Ubuntu 20.04, and I still don't have multiline headers. There's a tutorial on Novell's website that says vertical view will give you compressed, two-line headers, but I don't have them: https://www.novell.com/documentation/evolution/evolution/data/usage-mail-getnsend-read.html#b131ni8g

Comment: I searched the docs today (now using v3.38.2) and found the snippet that the Novell site mentions. However, when I switch to Vertical View the messages are displayed exactly the same way. You may want to post something on the Evolution mailing list about this: https://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/evolution-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vertical view should switch to the "for Wide View" view on its own. (Thanks Milan, [see Evolution Mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-list/2021-January/msg00019.html))

If not, go to `View -> Current View`: Highlight `For Wide View` if you are using [vertical view](https://www.novell.com/documentation/evolution/evolution/data/usage-mail-getnsend-read.html#b131ni8g). (Thanks Pete, [see Evolution Mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-list/2020-December/msg00048.html))

The "**multiline row**" can be used for the **Classical view** as well, just right-click the message list header and use "Add a Column..." and drag the "Messages" column to the header. Then remove all the other columns from the message list. The "for Wide View" does basically that.

[image]